# coloring with scale_color_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that look like this:

```
   d= data.frame(Name = c("B","A","A","B","A","B"),
                 Group= c("one","one","two","two","three","three"),
                 value=c(.5,.6,.7,.8,.4,.2))
      d

  Name Group value
1    B   one   0.5
2    A   one   0.6
3    A   two   0.7
4    B   two   0.8
5    A three   0.4
6    B three   0.2
```

when I plot it looks like this. notice where the A line is

```
 ggplot(d, 
             aes(x=factor(Group),
                 y=  value,
                 group= Name , color =Name)) +
      geom_point()+geom_line()
```

[image]

Now I want to color the lines using scale color manual like this:

```
      library(RColorBrewer)
  n <- 60
  qual_col_pals = brewer.pal.info[brewer.pal.info$category == 'qual',]
  col_vector = unlist(mapply(brewer.pal, qual_col_pals$maxcolors, rownames(qual_col_pals)))

    ggplot(d, 
         aes(x=factor(Group),
             y=  value,
             group= Name , color =Name)) +
  geom_point()+geom_line()  +
         scale_color_manual(name="name",
                   labels = unique(d$Name)
                  ,
                   values=  col_vector[14:(14+(length(unique(d$Name)) )-1 )]
     )
```

that produces this image where the "A" line is not correct. It is now the "B" line. How can I scale color manual to change the output using the colors in col_vector but keep the correct output?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `unique()` returns values in the order as they are located in your dataframe.

```
unique(d$Name)
[1] B A
Levels: A B
```

So you should use function `levels()`.

```
levels(d$Name)
[1] "A" "B"
```

If variable is not stored as factor, you can add `sort()` function.

```
sort(unique(d$Name))
[1] "A" "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are arbitrary changing the labels name with `labels` within the `scale_color_manual` function.

For example, run the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=factor(Group),y= value, 
                   group= Name , color =Name)) +geom_point()+geom_line()

p <- scale_color_manual(labels = c('ti','to'),
                        values=  col_vector[14:(14+(length(unique(d$Name)) )-1)])
```

And then, the first entry in `d$Name` is `B` (which is what `unique` is sending back)

I would advise creating a named vector first and then use that vector in `scale_color_manual`:

```
newPal<-setNames(col_vector[14:(14+(length(unique(d$Name)) )-1)],unique(d$Name))

p + scale_color_manual(values=newPal)
```